# Is there an idiom that says not to change a perfectly good thing?

Tags: phrase-request, idiom-request, proverbs

Is there an idiom/word/proverb that says not to change a perfectly good thing or something that works?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your question could be much improved by providing some more context. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Related not a dupe: [Looking for English proverb equal to “Chalti ka naam gaadi hai” = “a thing which runs is called a vehicle”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/85660/9161)

Comment: 'Do not look a gifthorse in the mouth' is tangential but related.

Comment: Related: Sufficient unto the day is the evil thereof.  (In more modern language, “Do not worry about tomorrow, for tomorrow will worry about itself. Each day has enough trouble of its own.”  But the “Sufficient unto the day” formulation is proverbial.)

Comment: @MJD Matthew 6:34

Comment: ''Don't kill the goose that lays the golden egg'' is completely different and not related.

Comment: From the world of windsurfing:  Never leave wind to find wind.

Answer (score 86):

If it ain't broke, don't fix it. (informal)

If it isn't broken, don't try to fix it.

Edit: You could leave out "try to" (I've heard it both ways), but the point of the proverb is that if you try to fix something that isn't broken, you won't be successful.

Comment: Definitely heard "don't fix it" a LOT more than "don't try to fix it". Expression definitely sounds American in origin but it's permeated quite well; I would definitely expect it to be understood if I said it here in Britain.

Comment: To be clear, the idiom is the sentence "If it ain't broke, don't fix it." I've never heard anyone say "if it isn't broken, don't try to fix it," and it would probably sound kind of funny if someone actually said that.

Comment: I ain't sure I could manage that. *shudders*. "If it isn't broken, don't fix it" certainly common in UK. Also (I'm not sure if this is just a BrE thing?) just the first part "if it isn't broken.." in the usual way.

Comment: "If it ain't broke, fix it until it is."

Comment: I'm not sure that the point of the proverb is that you won't be successful; rather it's that there's a risk that in trying to fix it you will break it, and since it's working fine as-is, there's little point in taking that risk.

Comment: Another 2 variant forms "If it works, don't [try to] fix it". Spoken as advice, it's almost always "If it ain't broke, don't fix it".

Comment: The wording “ain’t broke” is intentional. It’s meant to sound like advice handed down from an uneducated Southern American farmer. In other words, stop overthinking it and use common sense. https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/if-it-aint-broke-dont-fix-it.html

The phase “ain’t broke” ain’t broke; don’t fix it.

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney Love your two bits! It's also interesting how "ain't" is considered uneducated, but when you start learning English, you will learn the normal grammar types way, way earlier than when you willl start stumbling upon slangs, or maybe just focusing on songs/tv.

Comment: Tanner Swett: So the idiom is self-referential:-)

Comment: There's always [this flowchart](https://i.redd.it/pbicg4kxklu11.jpg), which, despite being labeled NSFW, I first saw at work (on a construction site).

Comment: @ulatekh Although quite funny in a generic way, that flowchart often explains why bridges fail, road guardrails can't withstand an impact, and buildings suddenly collapse.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: So you agree, my response was educational. LOL

Comment: @ulatekh Definitely! :)  As long as people see it as a visual representation of problematic behaviour and not a flowchart for recommended or acceptable behaviour.

Answer (score 33):

"Leave well enough alone."

Related, "Let sleeping dogs lie."

I've always heard user3169's answer as "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: Both of your suggestions are close, but to me they imply that the situation isn't "perfectly good." Instead they give me (native Am. English speaker) the impression that the situation is actually fairly bad, but any attempt to intervene is likely to make things worse

Comment: @BThompson That's fair enough, I agree.

Comment: Often heard in the form "Let well alone".

Comment: ''Let sleeping dogs lie'' sounds slightly literary and probably wouldn't be heard in everyday speech (at least not where I'm fron).

Comment: @BThompson - To me *Well Enough* and *Perfectly Good* do mean the same thing.  *Well enough* means not perfect but good/well enough.  *Perfectly good* means not perfect, we would just call that *perfect*, but good enough/functional.

Comment: @EllieK I generally agree that well enough and perfectly good are quite close in meaning; however, I don't parse "Leave well enough alone" as describing the situation as "well enough". I see it as describing the manner in which the speaker wants the listener to leave the situation alone. Again this implies (to me) that the situation is not good, and involving oneself is only likely to make things worse and/or drag the listener into a bad situation they needn't be part of

Comment: “Let sleeping dogs lie” has a different meaning. Something isn’t good and doesn’t work well, but if you attract attention to it and someone tries to fix it, you can bet that whoever tries to fix it will make it worse.

Comment: @gnasher729 That's why I said it was related. I didn't say it was exact.

Answer (score 15):

The expression "gilding the lily" means to add needless changes to something that's already of high value or near-perfect. So "don't gild the lily" would perhaps covey what you're looking for.

Or, "don't wreck a good thing" might fit, if the proposed changes were obviously going to lower its value. But this is very commonly used in cases where people are benefiting from a system which is non-standard or sub-optimal. Like if you found you were undercharged for a retail good, and were proposing to bring the error to the shop's attention so they could charge you the correct higher value, a friend might say "don't wreck a good thing". So similar in intent but perhaps not exactly what you're describing.

I'd go with "don't gild the lily".

Comment: To me, "gild the lily" has a connotation of overdoing it — i.e. trying to add extra, unneeded embellishments that actually make it worse.

Comment: @anotherdave Yes, quite right. I think I was really looking at the stress the OP was putting on the thing being "perfectly good" to begin with, even for changes that are nominally (or superficially) improvements.

Comment: yeah it's definitely a valid option (depending on the angle the OP is going for), was just adding for extra info

Comment: Except that "gilding the lily" is a re-wording of the original: "To gild refined gold, to paint the lily,
To throw a perfume on the violet,
To smooth the ice, or add another hue
Unto the rainbow..."  (Shakespeare, "King John", Act 4, scene 1)  It changes the entire meaning, which was that those acts are not only unnecessary, but pointless.  While a gilded lily might be rather fashionable among certain florist circles :-)

Comment: No, that's a totally different context and meaning.

Answer (score 9):

Here are two other proverbs that mean the same thing.

> "[Never change a running system](https://www.wordsense.eu/never_change_a_running_system/)"

> "[Don't change a winning team](https://www.wordsense.eu/don%27t_change_a_winning_team/)"

Also, the correct proverb is "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

Comment: I'm not sure I would call those proverbs. They sound like things you might say in specific situations where "if it ain't broke..." would also apply.

Comment: The above are all proverbs according to online dictionaries. I've edited the answer to include references.

Comment: In that case, I take it back, although I'm certainly surprised. Interestingly, the first of these cross-references "don't reinvent the wheel", which I think would be a great answer to the question.

Comment: I agree. That is a great answer as well. It denotes not wasting time on improving a thing that is already perfect.

Comment: “Never change a Running system” is no proverb. It’s about not changing a computer system while it is running, but stop the system, apply changes, restart it. Like you wouldn’t change the wheels of a car while driving, even when one needs changing: You stop the car first.

Comment: Do some research before answering. It is a proverb according to online dictionaries. I have referenced the source in my answer. You are right in that the proverb is derived from the field of computing. It means don't change something while it is working.

Comment: To be fair, according to your research, it is a proverb according _one_ online dictionary - that's all. If you can find more, you should post them to support your answer. Most dictionary definitions of the word "proverb" require the phrase to be well-known or familiar. I'm not going to downvote your answer, but I'm with @gnasher729 - I don't consider these to be proverbs in the literal sense.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a lighthearted way to joke about someone trying to fix something that they should have left alone, there's

"If it ain't broke, fix it 'til it is"

Comment: Or often heard in engineering, "if it ain't broke, marketing haven't had their say yet".

Comment: Or some say in corporate meetings, "If it ain't broke, break it to pass the time."

Comment: Another variation: If it ain't broke, it doesn't have enough features.

Comment: @SyedDanishAnwar haha nice

Comment: Ha.  My wife bought me a T-shirt with "Engineer's Motto: If it ain't broke, pull it apart and fix it."   Knows me too well.

Answer (score 4):

"The great is the enemy of the good."

When you have something that is good enough, do not risk making it worse, just because you are tempted to try to make it great.

Variations are often seen, such as, "The perfect is the enemy of the good."
See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_is_the_enemy_of_good

Comment: I’ve always heard this as, “The perfect is the enemy of the good.”

Comment: Often abused as “we can’t have the perfect, therefore we don’t even try to get the good” and rather continue using something bad. Say we have A which is really bad. C would be perfect but is difficult or expensive or both. Therefore we can’t get B which is cheap and much better than A but not perfect.

Answer (score 4):

"Don't reinvent the wheel"

Comment: That has a different meaning.  To me, it means, if you have something that's working, don't try to come up with another way to get things working.  If you're working in your yard moving earth using a wheel-barrow and your spouse suggests using a wagon instead, he/she's "re-inventing the wheel" (not a great example, but it does involve wheels).

Comment: In my experience, "reinventing the wheel" is said more about situations where your problem has a well-known standard solution, but you aren't aware of that solution so you try to come up with your own instead. The idea is that you should start by investigating existing approaches to a problem, rather than assume there are none.

Comment: To the previous two commenters: the question was about a phrase that means “not to change a perfectly good thing”. You’ve both described situations that fit this perfectly. I think “don’t reinvent the wheel” is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

**[Don't change horses in midstream](https://grammarist.com/phrase/dont-change-horses-in-midstream/)** is another one.  Sometimes seen as "swap" instead of "change", or "midrace" instead of "midstream".

Comment: I believe that the proverb means not changing position when part way through a project or campaign.

Comment: @SyedDanishAnwar It does perhaps imply a timeframe, i.e. after the "stream", you can then feel free to "change horses".  But it's at least a related concept, worth considering.  Don't know the exact context the OP is looking for.

Comment: Agree this says more about *when* to change rather than *what* to change. Whether or not the horse you're riding is any good, you should not change it in the middle of a stream. It doesn't imply that the horse you're on is good in any way, nor does it suggest that you wouldn't be better off with a different horse - just that you shouldn't change at a particular time.

Answer (score 2):

*"Don't mess with success"*

> "Don’t mess with success” is another way of saying “if it ain’t broke, don’t fix it.” “And I might say you don’t mess with success” was cited in print in 1964. It does not appear that any one person coined or popularized the simple rhyme.

https://www.barrypopik.com/index.php/new_york_city/entry/dont_mess_with_success

Answer (score 1):

"Never change a winning team"

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. Your answer could be improved by providing references. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score -1):

An algorithmic-focused answer:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: No. That means “don’t try to improve something until you understand it well enough to be sure that your changes will be an improvement, and that you can’t achieve a much bigger improvement if you gain more understanding”.